# Biquery table data performance

Tags: performance, google-bigquery

In **BigQuery** I have a table storing 237 GB data. I don't have any columns on which i can create partition as it does not store any date fields
When I am using it in the query the processing says 77 GB data will be processed but in bytes shuffled i see 7 GB data.
what is the actual GB of data processed here?
is there any way i could restructure this table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery operates column-wise. If you only choose the columns you really need in a query then you're optimizing cost already. Traditionally databases operate row-wise, so this can be a bit counter-intuitive.

There's also this great [blog article on optimizing for costs](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/cost-optimization-best-practices-for-bigquery).